# Execution point of Anonymous blocks in package in Oracle APEX Applications

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am calling two different procedures of a same package from two different execution points in ORACLE APEX page. This Package has anonymous block in it. (Written at the end of package body)

Execution point:  **On Load: Before "Body" regions.**
Calls : **pkg_name.proc_1**;

**Item Read Only section.**
Calls: **pkg_name.proc_2**;

I have put logging in the anonymous block in the package to check its execution. I observed that it is executing only once during page rendering.
But after the page rendering every time i make a call to the package (Through dynamic actions), the anonymous block gets executed.

I read, in oracle apex, every time a call is made to DB it will get a new DB connection from the pool.

How does the anonymous blocks execute in packages --> Once in a database session or Every time a package is called?

If Once in a database session, does that mean the entire page rendering happens in one database session unlike Dynamic actions?

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: The anonymous block in the package body is referred to as the **initialization part** of the package. It's usually executed once in a database session, the first time the package is called. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS00905

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  All rendering work is done together before the page is delivered to your browser - hence the single run of your package's anonymous block.  But each PL/SQL dynamic action executes as a separate AJAX request, which means each one connects to the database and disconnects independently.

Comment: To exactly summarize answers to my question. The entire rendering of page occurs in a single database session. And so the anonymous block is called only once.Thanks for clarifying